# Error : You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: react-native

I got this error when trying to import and use another component that I have created in another file. And I got an error like this :

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `Sidebar`.
```

This is my code to export component as default component in customDrawer.js which file is same directory:

```
const Sidebar = ({ isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme, ...props }) => {
  const handlePress = () => {
    props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
    props.navigation.navigate("Settings");
  };
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setIsDarkTheme();
  };
  // console.log('navi--?',props.navigation);
  return (
    <Container style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <Header
        style={{
          backgroundColor: colors.background,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
          marginTop: 70,
          borderWidth: 0,
        }}
      >
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="#ffffff" />
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress()}>
              {/* <Ionicons name="ios-options" size={28} color={colors.icon} /> */}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
              paddingRight: 20,
              paddingLeft: 20,
              paddingTop: 10,
            }}
          >
            <Text style={{ flex: 1, color: colors.text }}>Dark Theme</Text>
            <View>
              <Switch onValueChange={toggleTheme} value={isDarkTheme} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default Sidebar;
```

And then, in my App.js I have import components like this :

```
import Sidebar from "./customDrawer";
```

All imports I use in customDrawer.js :

```
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { Button, Container, Content, Header, Right } from "native-base";
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Switch } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

Comment: do you return the `SideBar` correctly?

Comment: That `//Some code in here` is the root of the problem. :)

Comment: @jted95 I have edited question with full code

Comment: @Nishant I have edited question with full code

Comment: At the last line of your Sidebar.js add **export default Sidebar;**

Comment: @AkshayShenoy I have added but error still there

Comment: Can you add file extension in your import and check? Like **import Sidebar from './customDrawer.js'** , this can happen if you have a styles file or some other file with same name maybe?

Comment: @AkshayShenoy I have double-checked all imports but only 1 "customDrawer" was found.

Comment: Can you show the imports in your customDrawer file

Comment: @AkshayShenoy you can check again, I have edited the question